Microphone Unmutes Itself on Sound on Win11 24H2
I have a Shure MV7 microphone, which also acts as a sound card. It's plugged into my computer via USB, but also has my headphones plugged in. It has a physical mute toggle, and also the ability to hear myself in addition to whatever is playing from my computer.
Issue: Since updating to Windows 11 Pro 24H2, whenever sound starts playing from my computer, the microphone unmutes itself. The red icon on the physical microphone that shows that it is muted disappears, showing that it is now unmuted. I can then hear the surrounding room because of my mix settings.
This happens on any noise generated - Outlook receiving email notification sound, YouTube video, etc. If I play a YouTube video and the microphone unmutes, I can then mute the microphone and continue playing the YouTube video. Subsequently if I pause and play the same video again, the microphone will become unmuted again.
There was no such unmute behavior prior to my update to Win11 Pro 24H2 (I was previously on whatever fully-updated Win11 Pro version came before it).
Other relevant details:

Windows version: Windows 11 Pro 24H2
Microphone firmware version: 1.2.19.0 (fully updated according to both Windows and the MOTIV Mix app)
MOTIV Mix version: 1.3.0.1524

I have tried the following:

Fully updating MOTIV app, firmware, Windows 11
Uninstalling & reinstalling firmware
System > Sound Settings > More Sound Settings > Recording > MV7 > "Advanced" tab > uncheck "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device"
Sound settings > Communications > "When Windows detects communications activity:" set to "Do nothing"
On the advice of user patkim in a comment: System > Sound, More Sound Settings, Recording tab, double click microphone in question, go to Listen tab, make sure "Listen to this device" is unchecked (it was already unchecked for me).
Just in case...I ran SFC /SCANNOW and all of the DISM.exe variants as well. No issues found.

None of this has stopped the microphone from unmuting itself. Does anyone have any ideas?

Don't know much, but just check the setting Listen to this device under Recording Properties and make sure that it's Unchecked. https://i.imgur.com/3QAM6MO.png
If your HW supports, create a Virtual Machine using apps like VMWare Player and create a Windows 10 VM, let it passthru to VM thru USB port and simulate how it behaves in Windows 10.

Thank you @patkim - unfortunately, that's already unchecked for that device. I have added this as a troubleshooting step above.

Just one more thing, when Microphone unmutes, go back to that setting, Tick it, OK and then again Untick it, does it Mute now?

How is the behavior if you check it again under Clean Boot? You can always revert back.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd#ID0EBBD=Windows_11

Use these options  to further isolate the issue: Check for Updates: Ensure both your microphone firmware and Windows are fully updated. Sometimes, manufacturers release updates to address compatibility issues with new OS versions.
Disable and Re-enable the Microphone: Disconnect and reconnect the microphone to see if that resets the settings.
Check for Third-Party Software: Sometimes, third-party software can interfere with microphone settings. Try disabling any audio-related software temporarily to see if it resolves the issue.
Report the Issue: Since this seems to be a widespread problem, consider reporting it to both Shure and Microsoft. You can use the Feedback Hub app on Windows to submit detailed feedback.
Use an Alternative Microphone: If possible, try using a different microphone to see if the issue persists. This can help determine if the problem is specific to the Shure MV7.
Check Privacy Settings: Double-check your microphone privacy settings in Windows. Make sure that apps are allowed to access your microphone2.
If none of these steps work, it might be worth reaching out to Shure support for further assistance. They may have additional insights or updates to address this issue.
